# function pointer and inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, templates, inheritance

I've got a generic function I'm using to sort some Objects in List class.

This function works very well but when I want to apply this function to a class using a function pointer to a member function in that class, it don't build.

The function is:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void DialogFaitListing::trie(T1 * list, T2 (T1::*fx)(quint16), T3 (T2::*crit)())
{
    for(int i(0);i<list->count();i++)
    {
        for(int j(i);j<list->count();j++)
        {
            if((((list->*fx)(i)).*crit)() > (((list->*fx)(j)).*crit)())
            {
                list->swap(i,j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where list is the Class which contains the list of objects, fx is the function pointer to access the object and crit is the objects comparison function for the sort.

When I build using this line:

```
trie(vend,&Vendeurs::getVend,&Vendeur::getNom);
```

I get this error:

```
dialogfaitlisting.cpp:459: erreur : no matching function for call to 
'DialogFaitListing::trie(Vendeurs*&, Vendeur (Vendeurs::*)(quint16), 
QString (Personne::*)())'
```

ps: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Are you [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)? Make things simpler!

Comment: You need to provide a simpler and more complete example. It's impossible to know all that could be wrong here without seeing how you declare the templated class, for example.  Also, the implementation of trie is not important here; it only adds noise to the question.  Try reducing your code to the smallest example that still produces the error and post the entire result (maybe 10 lines or so in a single .cpp files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&Vendeur::getNom`, despite being a member accessible through `Vendeur`, appears to have type `QString (Personne::*)()`. This makes `T2` ambiguous during template argument deduction: is it `Vendeur` or is it `Personne`?

A band-aid fix would be to put the burden on the caller of `trie` to explicitly convert it to `QString (Vendeur::*)()`, result in the following call:

```
trie(vend, &Vendeurs::getVend, static_cast<QString (Vendeur::*)()>(&Vendeur::getNom));
```

This is very verbose and inconvenient, considering that we're likely to find the same error each time the `crit`erion we wish to pass comes from a base class.

A better solution is to inhibit template argument deduction on one of the two spots where `T2` appears. I think it would make sense to choose the second spot for that:

```
template<typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void trie(T1 * list
     , T2 (T1::*fx)(quint16)
     , T3 (identity<T2>::type::*crit)());
```

Then in the call `T2` can only be deduced to be `Vendeur` and `&Vendeur::getNom` will be implicitly converted to `QString (Vendeur::*)()`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are simultaneously attempting to constrain `T2` to be `Vendeur` in the second argument to `trie` (because of `Vendeur Vendeurs::getVend(quint16)`) and `Personne` in the third argument (but I can't tell how it gets from `&Vendeur::getNom` to `Qstring Personne::function()`, unless there's some inheritance involved or something). You might need to post a little more code than that (class definitions, in particular).